# Djanjo dlib integration - pip install dlib have errors on macos 10.13.1

Tags: python, django, macos, pip, dlib

I am trying to install dlib library for my django project on my mac (macos 10.13.1), however i have this failure. I am using pip install dlib

below is the full execution with error

https://gist.github.com/axilaris/af361e54bd78a11fc35fc5029de69caa

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install Boost before trying to install the dlib library.

The simplest way is to download MacPorts, and run the following command:

```
sudo port install boost
```

I edited my post because I think I provided the wrong link.

Comment: Please edit your answer to at least include some of the material in the link. link-only answers are likely to become invalid if the url changes(which happens very often)